# How to update a column of a table using a function in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, function

Being a novice in ORACLE and programming in general I have difficulty in updating series of cells in a column of a table in oracle.
The table:

```
ad soyad not1 not1 not3 BN HN
Ayşe    Yılmaz    28    65    82
Melih    Türkmen    45    27    56
Cemile    Kara    54    65    99
Ragıp    Pekkan    62    48    85
Jale    Kale    48    75    52
Vehbi    Kemal    18    65    63
Mehmet    Hamarat    54    62    70
Murat    Çokbilir    25    28    32
Harun    Reşit    85    84    92
Cemal    Yamak    95    23    90
```

My function :

```
create or replace 
function basariNotu (a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  rbn NUMBER;
BEGIN
  rbn:=(a*0.2)+(b*0.2)+(c*0.6);
  RETURN rbn;
END basariNotu;
```

MY code that is supposed to update column 'bn' with rbn returned from the function:

```
DECLARE 
  d NUMBER;
  e NUMBER;
  f NUMBER;
  rbn NUMBER;
  j NUMBER;
BEGIN
  j:=1;
  LOOP
    SELECT not1 INTO d FROM student;
    SELECT not2 INTO e FROM student;
    SELECT not3 INTO f FROM student;
    basariNotu(d, e, f);
    UPDATE student SET bn=rbn WHERE bn= NULL;
    j:= j+1;
    IF j>10 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: you need to store the result of the function in a variable and then do the update, i mean change `basariNotu(d, e, f);` by `rbn:= basariNotu(d, e, f);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any appropriate `WHERE` clauses in your queries, and your LOOP has no relationship to the rows being processed. The `j` counter merely makes the loop do the same action 9 times. Not only that, but your predicate `bn= NULL` will always evaluate to FALSE so it will never update any rows.

I think you probably want something like this:

```
FOR r IN (
  SELECT student_id, not1, not2, not3
  FROM student
  WHERE bn IS NULL
  ) LOOP
  rbn := basariNotu(a => r.not1, b => r.not2, c = r.not3);
  UPDATE student SET bn=rbn WHERE student_id = r.student_id;
END LOOP;
```

The above code assumes your table has a unique identifier of some sort such as `student_id`. If it doesn't, you have more problems to deal with.

However, this is the slow-by-slow (row-by-row) style of programming, the habit of which you need to shake. The above could be done much more simply and efficiently with a single UPDATE statement, e.g.:

```
UPDATE student
SET bn = basariNotu(a => not1, b => not2, c = not3)
WHERE bn IS NULL;
```

For even better performance, you would avoid the function call completely, e.g.:

```
UPDATE student
SET bn = (not1*0.2)+(not2*0.2)+(not3*0.6)
WHERE bn IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the long and articulate comment but I don't have an identifier (AI or unique column). Regards

Comment: (1) the single UPDATE statement doesn't need an identifier; (2) if your table doesn't have a unique identifier there's something wrong with your data model.

Comment: Hello,This is homework so absence of a unique column was intentional. Regards, Aziz